Dell Latitude 7480 screen freezes and caps lock key light flickers
I have recently installed Ubuntu on my Dell Latitude 7480 and I came across this issue, whenever I boot up after some time screen freezes, caps lock light flickers and it becomes unresponsive and I have to force shut down. I think this is some kind of kernel panic but not exactly sure how to solve it. I tried updating BIOS, system, drivers but I still am facing this issue. one more this, in the bootloader screen when I edit it and type "nomodeset" it seems to work but with graphical issues (not recognizing the screen, I am not able to change refresh rate and more.) have you ever had this problem? what can I try to fix it? (this is not only Ubuntu's problem, I face this issue with all the distros I tried, Arch, Mint, Fedora, Manjaro) I 've never had this issue on Windows.
